# handle PDF content in HTTP callout

Tags: apex, callout

I am making a callout to a third party and response is a PDF file. However, on salesforce side seems like PDF is getting corrupted.Seems like method "getBodyAsBlob" does not work.

```
HTTP h = new HTTP();
    HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('endpoint');
    request.setHeader('contentType', 'application/json');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    string str = 'payload';
    request.setBody(JSON.serialize(str));
    HTTPResponse resp = h.send(request); 
    if(resp.getStatusCode()==200){ 
    blob response = resp.getBodyAsBlob();
    Attachment attach = new Attachment();
    attach.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
    attach.name = 'myfile111.pdf';
    attach.parentId = '001XXXXXXX';
    attach.body = response; //blob.ValueOf(response);
    insert attach;
```

Could anyone suggest the best way to resolve this?

Comment: Are they sending  base64 string?

Comment: I think its in binary form but not sure.

Comment: Your code is working fine, I just changed the endpoint to a sample pdf endpoint "https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/212/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/api_console.pdf" and it saved pdf in the proper format and is viewable.

Comment: Could you share the sample end point? I tried with https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/212/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/api_console.pdf

Comment: Yeah same what you tried. I can see attachments created and attached.

Comment: Got it. Working on my side as well. Thanks for confirming the same. Just one question..in case if they are sending base64, should I will be able to convert into blob and get proper PDF? I mean is there any kind of data loss on changing base64 to blob.

Comment: as it had code snippets, i have responded it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming they are sending a Base64 string, you then have to use EncodingUtil to decode a base 64 file to blob.

```
EncodingUtil.base64Decode("base64String");
```

So your code will be

```
 HTTP h = new HTTP();
HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest();
request.setEndpoint('endpoint');
request.setHeader('contentType', 'application/json');
request.setMethod('GET');
string str = 'payload';
request.setBody(JSON.serialize(str));
HTTPResponse resp = h.send(request); 
if(resp.getStatusCode()==200){ 
    String base64Response = resp.getBody();
    Attachment attach = new Attachment();
    attach.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
    attach.name = 'myfile111.pdf';
    attach.parentId = '001XXXXXXX';
    attach.body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Response); 
    insert attach;
}
```

There won't be any data loss or corruption if they were sending proper base64 string.

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm

Comment: I have the same problem. I am not sure what type of data i am getting as response body, When I use ``EncodingUtil.base64Decode();, it throws this error `System.StringException: Unrecognized base64 character: %` .