# Error when pulling PDF from HTTP response

Tags: apex, callout, pdf, http

I have a question regarding this post:  [handle PDF content in HTTP callout](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217628/handle-pdf-content-in-http-callout/284763#284763)

When I try the above code I'm getting this:

"Unrecognized base64 character: %"

The logs show this as well:

19:53:04:658 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [285]|base64Response|"%PDF-1.3\r\n%����\r\n3 0 (82794 more) ..."

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a base-64 string, it's the actual binary PDF data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a blob directly. Why not save the blob directly using [resp.getBodyAsBlob()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse.htm)

```
String endPoint ='http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/rel1/doc/en-us/static/pdf/salesforce_query_search_optimization_developer_cheatsheet.pdf';


HTTP h = new HTTP();
HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest();
request.setEndpoint(endPoint);
request.setHeader('contentType', 'application/json');
request.setMethod('GET');
HTTPResponse resp = h.send(request);
if(resp.getStatusCode()==200){

    Attachment attach = new Attachment();
    attach.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
    attach.name = 'myfile111.pdf';
    attach.parentId = '0010C000006ReQW';
    attach.body = resp.getBodyAsBlob();
    insert attach;
}
```

In my code, I am downloading a SF document PDF and saving it as an attachment on an account record

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks so much!

Comment: @George can you accept answer? It will help someone with similar querry reach solution faster