# get pdf from external url

Tags: apex, integration, pdf, files, getcontentaspdf

In the response from 3rd party I am getting url, I want to grab that url and save that pdf in a salesforce object.
If I manually use that url and paste in browser it downloads the file. But when I use pagereference method to show in apex it doesnt show the file.

```
String url1 = 'some external url' //this I get in httpresponse from 3rd party
Pagereference pg = new Pagereference(url1); 
Blob b = pg.getContentAsPDF();
```

How can I grab this url and save pdf file in Salesforce.

Is there any other way to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [handle PDF content in HTTP callout](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217628/handle-pdf-content-in-http-callout)

Comment: If the external url is already giving you a pdf, then there should be no need to `.getContentAsPDF()`. `.getContent()` should do, I would think (if it works at all). I'm not sure about the limitations of using `PageReference` with external URLs (I know it performs a GET request to the page, but that's about it).

Comment: the problem is in my repsonse I am getting url and not pdf blob. So it is not working.

Comment: When I click on external url it downloads pdf in my laptop. That url doesnt show pdf itself.